# Show the alert when user click on the button if the condition is true in php

Tags: php

i have query like this

```
SELECT      COUNT(*) 
FROM        mdl_assigncourses 
INNER JOIN  mdl_moog_groups ON mdl_assigncourses.groupid = mdl_moog_groups.id 
WHERE       groupid =  '34'
```

if the count value will be greater than zero i want to show some alert to the user... when the user click on the below button..and instead of goupid='34' i want to pass this value `<?php echo $row->id;?>`

```
<tr class="gradeX"> 
    <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->group_name;?></td> 
    <td>
        <a href="assigncourse.php?groupid=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><div style="background-color:#FF7F50; width:30px; padding-left:8px; padding-top:4px; height:28px; color:white">
            <em class="icon-plus"></em></div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="groupedit.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><div style="background-color:#8FBC8F; width:30px; padding-left:8px; padding-top:3px; height:28px; color:white">
            <em class="fa fa-edit"></em></div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <?php
    $result = "
    SELECT      COUNT( * ) 
    FROM        mdl_assigncourses
    INNER JOIN  mdl_moog_groups ON mdl_assigncourses.groupid = mdl_moog_groups.id
    WHERE       groupid = '37' delete_status='0'";

    if(sizeOf($result) > 0 ){
    ?>
    <td>
        <a href="groupdelete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('you cant delete this record?');">
            <div style="background-color:#CD5C5C; width:30px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:3px; height:28px; color:white">
                <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <?php    
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <td>
        <a href="groupdelete.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('you can delete this record?');">
            <div style="background-color:#CD5C5C; width:30px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:3px; height:28px; color:white">
                <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <?php 
    }?> 
</tr>
```

Can anyone help me how to do this

thanks in advance..

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload/redirect, then I suggest looking into using jQuery/AJAX call to query the database, then display the alert (or not), depending on the result.

Comment: if results greater than zero i just want to show like you cant delete this record..if results less that zero you can delete alert and it will be deleted from record..

Comment: OK, so change your `WHERE groupid='34'` to something to the effect of `WHERE groupid={$row->id}` (look into prepared statments). Then you could then just use an `if()` statement to check whether your query returns any rows. Displaying the table cell content accordingly.

Comment: actually i tried like that..but its not worjking properly..

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried. It may be easier to get an idea of what you want to achieve and how to solve your problem.

Comment: i updated check once..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154534/discussion-between-justbaron-and-user200).